# Как будет правильно задать права на папку?

Tags: linux, unix, chmod, chown

Есть задание: задать такие права на каталог, чтобы все юзеры могли создавать в ней файлы, а удалять -- только каждый свой файл. Вот понятия не имею, как это провернуть. Помогите

Comment: Помнится мне такое задание в курсе Cisco (Linux Essentials)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решён и снят, спасибо!

```
'chmod 1777 /path/to/dir'
```